# SSRS combine and aggregate two reports into single report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a situation where i need to combine two reports developed from different data set into single report.

Both reports have same metrics and the user just need the two report to be combined as single report. I tried implementing the sub report but i do not get the output as required. Attached is the sample image of the output i am looking for.Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create three tables/matrices, one for each data set and a third with the sum of the two, either by plain sum in SSRS or using a third data set with aggregation by SQL.